# Mysql Issue (eating up CPU

Tags: php, mysql, server, cpanel, whm

I'd like to preface this by saying im a total newbie when it comes to server administration.  With that out of the way.....

I'm scratching my head wondering why my WHM daily process log is showing such a high % of max cpu usage (160%, which i assume means 1.6 cores fully utilized)

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir/usr --datadir/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --usermysql --log-error/var/lib/mysql/xxx.yyyyyyy.com.err --open-files-limit5000000 --pid-file/var/lib/mysql/xxx.yyyyyyy.com.pid
```

I'm not sure what this means... Is there some kind of error with my settings?  What should i tweak?

Also, mailnull is using up quite a bit of CPU as well.

What should my next moves be?

Comment: kind of impossible to answer

Comment: you need to analyse things like the slow query log, and monitor general process activity to see what it is exactly that's eating the cpu. not really a question for stackoverflow tho

Comment: serverfault stack exchange ( http://serverfault.com/ ) *might* be a more useful place to ask, but only once you've got a more specific question to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Run [SHOW PROCESSLIST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html) to see queries being processed and their run time. Enable [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html) to catch slow queries. Use [mysqltuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl/) to see tuning suggestions.